# How to retrieve and store data with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to return multiple data (variables) from PHP instead of just 1 piece of returned html code.

Right now I got this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    cache: false
})
.done(function(html) {
    $('video').attr('src', html);
});
```

But I want to be able to do someting similar to this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    cache: false
})
.done(function(data) {
    $('video').attr('src', data.videoUrl);
    $('video').attr('poster', data.posterUrl);
});
```

In my **test.php** I have this:

```
$posterUrl = "thumbnail.png";
$videoUrl = "video.mp4";

echo $posterUrl;
echo $videoUrl;
```

How can I accomplish something like that?

Comment: well, you can't. you'll have to echo your data in json format instead if you want to use it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way? JSON.

JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    dataType: "JSONP"
}).done(function(json) {
    $("video").attr("src", json.videoURL).attr("poster", json.posterURL);
});
```

PHP:

```
$output = array();
$output["posterURL"] = "poster.png";
$output["videoURL"] = "video.mp4";

echo json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to json_encode the response like this.

```
$response = array("videoUrl"=>"video.mp4","posterUrl"=>"video.mp4");

echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a JSON instead of a string.

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/